# How to read client side uploaded XML

Tags: jquery, xml

I want to read a client side XML file uploaded via upload file dialog.  I am trying to read like below. I dont know how to proceed. Please help me on this..

```
 // Here I want to read the uploaded xml
 function(xml) {
        alert('Successfully loaded');
        $(xml).find('name').each(function(){
            var qid = $(this).text();
        });
 }
```

My requirement is reading the XML at client side itself without uploading it to the server.
[here](http://jsfiddle.net/GwQvB/3/) is the fiddle..
Thanks

Comment: Can you include the XML ? is it always the same format ie XML tags ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the XML file has been uploaded to your server you can execute a AJAX request to read it, assuming it is publicly accessible:

```
$.get(
    "\path\to-uploaded.xml",
    function(xml) {
        alert('Successfully loaded');
        $(xml).find('name').each(function() {
            var qid = $(this).text();
        });
    }
}
```

If the XML file is not publicly accessible once it's been uploaded, you'll need to use a server-side technology such as PHP or ASP.Net to read it.

Comment: Thanks for your response.. Can't we read the xml using the path given in the upload dialog. I mean to say that.. Cant we read without submitting it to the server assuming the provided path is the xml path..

Comment: I'm afraid not. For security reasons a browser has absolutely no access to anything on a visitors computer.

Comment: :-) Thank you very much for your valuable time